# Restsharp RequestBody challenge, JSON format issue?

Tags: c#, json, geocoding, restsharp, esri

TLDR: I've got a functioning C# script that calls the ESRI geocoding service. It passes addresses in, and gets LAT/LON data back. This works fine so long as I embed addresses in the URL. I'm having difficulty getting similar code to function with the address content in the body of the call. Goal here is to call REST service with 500+ addresses at a time.

Immediately below is a script that works fine as long as I've embedded the addresses as part of the URL. It handles 2-5 addresses, no problem. But (predictably enough) -- when trying to increase to 100 addresses I get an error "Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long."

````
```C# 
SqlDataAdapter geoA = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLStatement, GEOconn);
DataSet GeoDS = new DataSet();
geoA.Fill(GeoDS, "records");
var obj = JObject.FromObject(GeoDS);
obj["records"] = new JArray(obj["records"].Select(jo => new JObject(new JProperty("attributes", jo))));
string geoAJSON = obj.ToString();
geoAJSON = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(geoAJSON);
var con1 = "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses?f=pjson&token=abc123&outFields=ResultID,Status,Score,Addr_type,ShortLabel,City,Subregion,RegionAbbr,Postal,PostalExt,Country,X,Y&addresses=";
var client = new RestClient(con1 + geoAJSON);
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "AGS_ROLES=abc123");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
ESRIcls esri = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ESRIcls>(response.Content);
```
````

So I'm trying to make use of the body of the URL request, and push all the addresses to the body. The script snippet I've used to this point is below (slight modification from above).

```
SqlDataAdapter geoA = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLStatement, GEOconn);
DataSet GeoDS = new DataSet();
geoA.Fill(GeoDS, "records");
var obj = JObject.FromObject(GeoDS);
obj["records"] = new JArray(obj["records"].Select(jo => new JObject(new JProperty("attributes", jo))));
string geoAJSON = obj.ToString();               
geoAJSON = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(geoAJSON);     
var con1 = "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses?f=pjson&token=abc123&outFields=ResultID,Status,Score,Addr_type,ShortLabel,City,Subregion,RegionAbbr,Postal,PostalExt,Country,X,Y";
var client = new RestClient(con1)
client.Timeout = -1
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddJsonBody(geoAJSON);
//request.AddParameter("application/json", geoAJSON, ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "AGS_ROLES=abc123");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
ESRIcls esri = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ESRIcls>(response.Content);
```

On running, I'm getting the following error on occasion of executing that IRestResponse line:

> error code 400  extendedCode -2147467259 message: Unable to complete
> operation.

For reference, here is a grab of the content of the geoAJSON variable. I've tried multiple variations of url encoding and not. Unclear what part of this I've got wrong and would appreciate any suggestions.

```
    "{\r\n  \"records\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"attributes\": {\r\n        
    \"OBJECTID\": 144,\r\n        \"Address\": \"02483 BERRY RD\",\r\n        
    \"City\": \"CEDARTOWN\",\r\n        \"Region\": \"GA\",\r\n        
    \"Postal\": \"30125\"\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      
    \"attributes\": {\r\n        \"OBJECTID\": 145,\r\n        \"Address\": 
    \"0N321 SILVERLEAF BLVD\",\r\n        \"City\": \"WHEATON\",\r\n        
    \"Region\": \"IL\",\r\n        \"Postal\": \"60187-2913\"\r\n      }\r\n    
    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"attributes\": {\r\n        \"OBJECTID\": 146,\r\n        
    \"Address\": \"1\",\r\n        \"City\": \"ROME\",\r\n        
    \"Region\": \"GA\",\r\n        \"Postal\": \"30165\"\r\n      }\r\n    
    }\r\n  ]\r\n}"
```

Answer (score 0):

For others facing similar challenge with esri geocoding, the following worked

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GeoCode
{
    class GeoCode_Main
    {
        readonly static string strDDInstance = @"server";       // where is geo.datasources table?
        readonly static string strddDB = "database";
        readonly static string connDDstring = "Data Source=" + strDDInstance + ";Initial Catalog=" + strddDB + ";Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets = True";
        readonly static int intBatchSize = 250;                     // how many rows to send to batch geocoder at one time?
        public static int intRowsProcessed = 0;             // how many geocode addresses have we done this run?

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Launching GeoCode_Main_BI routine");
            string SQLStatement = "select top " + intBatchSize + " MAFid as OBJECTID, FMCaddr as Address, FMCcity as City, FMCstate as Region, FMCzip as Postal from maf.addresses where GSscore is null "; // and bitwise_nulls = 30 and MAFid < 750";
            string SQLTempRecCount = "select count(*) as RecCnt from maf.addresses_temp";
            using SqlConnection GEOconn = new SqlConnection(connDDstring);
            GEOconn.Open();

            // if maf.addresses_temp has data in it -- some prior run failed -- hit the exit ramp until that gets fixed
            SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(SQLTempRecCount, GEOconn);
            int MafTempRecCnt = (int)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            if (MafTempRecCnt > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Rows exist in maf.addresses_temp and they shouldn't -- bailing out - 1");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return; } // bailout
            do
            {
                // now open up maf.addresses and see if any rows flagged for geocoding. 
                SqlDataAdapter geoDA = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLStatement, GEOconn);
                DataSet GeoDS = new DataSet();
                geoDA.Fill(GeoDS, "records");
                int GeoDSCnt = GeoDS.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                // likewise - if no recs return -- just exit
                if (GeoDSCnt == 0)
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("Finished processing records - about to exit");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return;
                }
                intRowsProcessed += GeoDSCnt;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} rows so far", intRowsProcessed);

                var JSONobj = JObject.FromObject(GeoDS);  
                JSONobj["records"] = new JArray(JSONobj["records"].Select(jo => new JObject(new JProperty("attributes", jo))));
                string geoAJSON = JSONobj.ToString();     
                var client = new RestClient("https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/geocodeAddresses");
                client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.AddParameter("addresses", geoAJSON);
                request.AddParameter("forStorage", "true");
                request.AddParameter("outFields", "ResultID,Status,Score,Addr_type,ShortLabel,City,Subregion,RegionAbbr,Postal,PostalExt,Country,X,Y");
                request.AddParameter("f", "pjson");
                request.AddParameter("token", "blahblah");
                request.AddParameter("Cookie", "blahblah");
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                ESRIcls esri = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ESRIcls>(response.Content);
                int Cntr = 0;
                while (Cntr < esri.locations.Count)
                {
                    //                                Console.WriteLine(esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.Addr_type);
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand
                    {
                        CommandText = "maf.spPopMAF",
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                        Connection = GEOconn
                    };
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MAFid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.ResultID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GSstatus", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.Status;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GSscore", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.Score;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GSaddresstype", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.Addr_type;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GSaddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.ShortLabel;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GScity", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.City;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GScounty", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.Subregion;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GSstate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.RegionAbbr;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GSzip5", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.Postal;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GSzip4", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.PostalExt;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GSlongitude", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.X;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GSlatitude", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.Y;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@GScountry", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = esri.locations[Cntr].attributes.Country;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Cntr++;
                };
                // Console.WriteLine("Just populated esri feed into maf.addresses_temp table");
                // now move content from temp to maf.addresses
                var cmdsp = new SqlCommand
                {
                    CommandText = "maf.spESRIGeoCodedUpToMAFAddresses",
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                    Connection = GEOconn
                };
                cmdsp.ExecuteNonQuery();
                // Console.WriteLine("Just executed maf.spESRIGeoCodedUpToMAFAddresses routine");
                SqlCommand scTemp = new SqlCommand(SQLTempRecCount, GEOconn);
                int MafTempRecCnt2 = (int)scTemp.ExecuteScalar();
                if (MafTempRecCnt2 > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Rows exist in maf.addresses_temp and they shouldn't -- bailing out - 2 ");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    return; }
            }
            while (true);
        }
    }


    public class SpatialReference
    {
        public int wkid { get; set; }
        public int latestWkid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Attributes
    {
        public int ResultID { get; set; }
        public string Loc_name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public Decimal Score { get; set; }
        public string Match_addr { get; set; }
        public string LongLabel { get; set; }
        public string ShortLabel { get; set; }
        public string Addr_type { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string PlaceName { get; set; }
        public string Place_addr { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public Decimal Rank { get; set; }
        public string AddBldg { get; set; }
        public string AddNum { get; set; }
        public string AddNumFrom { get; set; }
        public string AddNumTo { get; set; }
        public string AddRange { get; set; }
        public string Side { get; set; }
        public string StPreDir { get; set; }
        public string StPreType { get; set; }
        public string StName { get; set; }
        public string StType { get; set; }
        public string StDir { get; set; }
        public string BldgType { get; set; }
        public string BldgName { get; set; }
        public string LevelType { get; set; }
        public string LevelName { get; set; }
        public string UnitType { get; set; }
        public string UnitName { get; set; }
        public string SubAddr { get; set; }
        public string StAddr { get; set; }
        public string Block { get; set; }
        public string Sector { get; set; }
        public string Nbrhd { get; set; }
        public string District { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string MetroArea { get; set; }
        public string Subregion { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string RegionAbbr { get; set; }
        public string Territory { get; set; }
        public string Zone { get; set; }
        public string Postal { get; set; }
        public string PostalExt { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string LangCode { get; set; }
        public int Distance { get; set; }
        public Decimal X { get; set; }
        public Decimal Y { get; set; }
        public Decimal DisplayX { get; set; }
        public Decimal DisplayY { get; set; }
        public Decimal Xmin { get; set; }
        public Decimal Xmax { get; set; }
        public Decimal Ymin { get; set; }
        public Decimal Ymax { get; set; }
        public string ExInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public Decimal score { get; set; }
        public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
    }

    public class ESRIcls
    {
        public SpatialReference spatialReference { get; set; }
        public IList<Location> locations { get; set; }
    }
}
```